# In Firebug 1.6.0, how do you tell what url triggered a 404 error?

Tags: url-rewriting, firebug, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to work out some url rewrite issues and I'm trying to get firebug to help me.  I'm getting 404 errors on misguided urls and I would like to see which ones are off.  That way I can examine why they are off and perhaps see an easy solution.

Anyway I can't seem to get firebug to show me the original urls, and I can't seem to find it in the request data on the net tab.

Firebug Net Tab:
[image: Firebug 404 error readout]

Can someone tell how I can see what urls are triggering these 404s?

Comment: For me I just tried going to http://stackoverflow.com/notexist.htm and it shows the full URL on mouse over, perhaps there is something a bit weird going on. Maybe fiddler will shed more light.

Answer (score 1):

Float your mouse over "GET 404" and the url shows up. You can also click the plus and expand it to see more information like the url and the actual response that was sent.

Comment: It doesn't say "GET 404" for me as per the screenshot. It says "GET resourcename.htm" etc. Does it say "Get 404" for you?

Comment: I just realized that he named the resource 404. if you go to the website listed you can see what is happening. its trying to access http://prosperlea.com/404 thats why it just says 404.

Comment: are you saying it's getting 404 on 404?

Answer (score -1):

You can expand the line by clicking the plus sign.  There is a ton of information about the request and response in the tabs that will show up after the line is expanded.