# How do you tell in Firebug what URL is throwing a 404 Not Found error in the Net Tab?

Tags: firebug

I know this has been discussed in this topic: [In Firebug 1.6.0, how do you tell what url triggered a 404 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567227/in-firebug-1-6-0-how-do-you-tell-what-url-triggered-a-404-error), but I'm thinking my situation is a little bit different. When I look at the net tab it shows the GET is referring to the 404 Not Found page. Here's a screenshot:

http://www.fsclive.com/images/FirebugGrab.jpg

The odd thing is if you go to this page, it works just fine and there is no issue accessing this page. I'm wondering if it's pointing to the 404 Not Found page only after it can't access whatever script or object that it's trying to access to begin with.

So my main questions are what could be causing this and how can I tell what the original request was that may have redirected to the 404 page after not being able to find it?

Thanks for any help/ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I tell what the original request was

Firebug is currently not able to display the initiator of a network request, because Firefox doesn't provide the necessary API yet. See [issue 1911](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/1911) and the corresponding [Mozilla bug 563623](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=563623) for more info on this.

You can disable the redirection to the custom 404 page in your development environment, so the original URL is displayed within the *Net* panel.

> what could be causing this

Checking with Web Inspector showed that on the home page of davincilabs.com I get a 404 error for "http://www.davincilabs.com/davincicon/themes/DV_form_modern_black/galleria/galleria-1.2.6.min.js".

Comment: Just tried that and found that it worked great! Thanks for your help! I knew it was something minute that was causing it, but the knowledge of how to better use not only Firebug but the built in Web Inspector helps significantly.