# In the Network pane of developer tools, see what script called another script

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

In the Net pane of developer tools I can see all the various scripts that are called on a webpage. I can do <kbd>Ctl</kbd>`+`<kbd>F</kbd> on the html source to find the script, or link to the script (like with the `src` attribute).

Sometimes however, scripts call scripts which are called by other scripts, so I can't see the actual reference to the script on the page. Is there anyway I can see exactly what called a particular script. Like a way in the net panel (eg on mainsite.com) I could see `b.thomas.com` was called by the call `a.thomas.com`. Then I could see that on the page, the chain started with `<script src="a.thomas.com" type="text/javascript"></script>`. The header I see in dev tools always simply says mainsite.com.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19565853/432681.

Firebug is currently [not able to display the origin of a request](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=1772) directly because of [missing APIs in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=563623), though you can use the `Referer` header of each request as an indication.